# Given the coordinates of two convex polygons, is there any formula to calculate the percentage overlap between them?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, area, polygons

Say the coordinates of the vertices of two polygons, A and B, have been given. Let's say A is an n-sided polygon with the coordinates of its vertices ($x_{a1}, y_{a1})$ through ($x_{an}, y_{an})$, and B is an m-sided polygon with the coordinates of its vertices ($x_{b1}, y_{b1})$ through ($x_{bm}, y_{bm})$. How do I calculate the percentage area of overlap between the two.

I know that broadly its going to be the following:

$Percentage$ $overlap = \frac{Area \, of \,  intersection \, of \, A \, and \, B}{Area \, of \, A \, + \, Area \, of \, B \, - \, Area \, of \,  intersection \, of \, A \, and \, B}$

But, how to determine the area of intersection of the two polygons?

**P.S.:** If it turns out that there's no generalized answer for any type of convex polygon, let's take the polygons to be equi-angular, but they can still have any orientation, like the example shown below where the square is "tilted", and they can each have their sides of unequal length (like, rectangle instead of square, etc).

Or if even that is not possible, let's take the two polygons to have the same number of sides (i.e., they're both rectangles, or both hexagons, etc) - but they can still be rotated, or tilted, at different angles.

[image]

Comment: Well there's an approach - there's a well known formula known as the "shoelace" formula which allows you to compute the area of a convex polygon given it's vertices. Just apply it to each of the three regions ($A$, $B$ and the intersection polygon) and use the percentage formula

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this. However, with the shoelace formula, we'll only be able to calculate the area of the two polygons. But, since we don't know the intersection coordinates, how do we calculate the area of the intersection?

Comment: By finding the intersection coordinates. There are algorithms for this. See for instance https://www.swtestacademy.com/intersection-convex-polygons-algorithm/ or http://www-cgrl.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Plante/CompGeomProject-EPlante/algorithm.html.

Comment: If the vertices are known you could find the every intersection and the areas. It is just a lengthy tedious work.

Comment: If you're satisfied with a numerical approximation, take the bounding box of the two shape and keep sampling all points between until you reach the error bound that you're looking for. You can use raycasting or the winding number to compute this quickly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon